# I can't retrieve the values from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

```
$raw_results=mysql_query("SELECT resort_name FROM resorts WHERE resort_id=(SELECT resort_id FROM resort_place WHERE place_id=(SELECT place_id FROM place WHERE place='$query')) ") or die(mysql_error());
$check_num_rows=mysql_num_rows($raw_results);
$solutions = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($raw_results)) {
$solutions[] = $row['solution'];
}
```

This is my code and it returns an error message like

> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Unable to save result set in C:\xampp\htdocs\search\news.php on line 131
>   Subquery returns more than 1 row

can any one help me to retrieve the values from the data base...

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

this will yield the same result with you multiple subquery.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.resort_name 
FROM    resorts a
        INNER JOIN resort_place b
            ON a.resort_id = b.resort_id
        INNER JOIN place c
            ON b.place_id = c.place_id
WHERE   c.place='$query'
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection` if the value(*s*) came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Use prepared statements using `mysqli_` or `PDO` functions instead. Your query can be accomplished using an explicit `JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT resorts.resort_name
FROM resorts
JOIN resort_place ON resort_place.resort_id = resorts.resort_id
JOIN place ON place.place_id = resort_place.place_id
WHERE place.place = '$query'
```

Answer (score 0):

use IN operator like place_id in (your sub query here)

```
  $raw_results=mysql_query("SELECT resort_name FROM resorts WHERE resort_id IN 
       (SELECT resort_id FROM resort_place WHERE place_id IN 
            (SELECT place_id FROM place WHERE place='$query')
       ) 
  ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are wise, you could do better than nesting queries.

If you really want to do `AND my_column_id = (SELECT something FROM ...)`
make sure that the subquery returns only one row, maybe by ending it with `LIMIT 0, 1`.